# How to create metro tiles in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a app in JQuery Mobile, and the home page is metro style. How do I show metro UI? Thanks.

Comment: This is not very constructive. Please elaborate your attempts and show us non working code you need help with.

Comment: Thanks. I will send the code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this blog. He has listed some awesome themes for jquery mobile.

```
http://www.gajotres.net
```

Just search the blog entries.

Comment: Thanks. I have choose jqMetro.